# SQLAlchemy type object 'Date' has no attribute '_set_parent_with_dispatch'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy and simple model pattern.

```
  class Mail(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'mail'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        date = Column(Date, nullable=False)
```

And i getting stupid mistake

```
AttributeError: type object 'Date' has no attribute '_set_parent_with_dispatch'
```

Im tried last version of sqlalchemy 1.0.6, and previous, and even very old version 0.7.x — everywhere the same error.

Line 72 of this file https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py#L72

Comment: if your `Date` an `sqlalchemy.Date` or some other definition/import in your file?

Comment: @van, only one import `from sqlalchemy import Column, Date`

Comment: Before the code you run could you please run `print(Date)` and see if it produces `class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.Date'>`?

Comment: All right: `<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.Date'>`

Comment: I really do not know what the problem is, but still I think that in your code you must override `Date` name with something else. I post some code here (https://gist.github.com/vanife/fd6fff18c8a69688aebf), which works for me with exactly the same SA version. Again, look in your code where you *redefine* `Date`, or post more code for people to help you.

Comment: :-)  Definitely!
Before that I used an «sqlacodegen» for model code generation. ))) One of the tables has name as «Date», and somewhere in over 1500 lines was declared class:  
`class Date(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'date'`
Conclusion: The use of prefixes for naming tables is the good practice. @van, thank you!

Comment: Thanks @Van
I have just imported DateTime like this 
"from sqlalchemy import (Column, String, Integer, DateTime)"
 and it worked for me.

Comment: I would have upvoted this answer if it was not just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Though your question doesn't appear to have this issue, a similar error can be caused by bad parameter ordering. Check the order of your variables in your `Column()`.  If you have them out of order, you can get this error.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

No one answered this question with the answer above, so I will.  This error can happen when you have inadvertently named one of your SQLAlchemy model mapper classes "Date" which causes a collision with SQLAlchemy's Date class.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import a Date package.`from sqlalchemy import Date`

Comment: Before that I used an «sqlacodegen» for model code generation. ))) One of the tables has name as «Date», and somewhere in over 1500 lines was declared class: class Date(Base): __tablename__ = 'date' Conclusion: The use of prefixes for naming tables is the good practice