# SQLAlchemy AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_set_parent_dispatch'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I happen to run into a problem which I've never seen before using sqlalchemy based on the same ORM schema. Here's a snippet of code.

```
@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    """ provide a transaction scope around a series of operations """
    session = db_session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()

with session_scope() as session:
    query = (session
             .query(*orm_lst)
             .filter(and_(*filter_lst)).group_by(*group_by_lst)
             .order_by(*order_by_lst))
```

When I look into the `query` variable, there's a `statement` variable saying **AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_set_parent_with_dispatch'**. And here's part of traceback.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ...
> File "D:\software\conda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 474, in statement
> return stmt._annotate({'no_replacement_traverse': True})
> File "D:\software\conda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 235, in _annotate
> return Annotated(self, values)
> File "D:\software\conda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\selectable.py", line 3712, in **init**
> element.c
> File "D:\software\conda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 764, in **get**
> obj.**dict**[self.**name**] = result = self.fget(obj)
> File "D:\software\conda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\selectable.py", line 686, in columns
> self._populate_column_collection()
> File "D:\software\conda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\selectable.py", line 3462, in _populate_column_collection
> name_is_truncatable=True)
> File "D:\software\conda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 3590, in _make_proxy
> name=name if name else self.name)
> File "D:\software\conda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 1445, in _make_proxy
> _proxies=[self], *fk)
> File "D:\software\conda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 1248, in **init**
> self._init_items(*args)
> File "D:\software\conda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 79, in _init_items
> item._set_parent_with_dispatch(self)
> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_set_parent_with_dispatch'

Please, anyone can help?

Comment: What is in `orm_lst`?

Comment: there're might be various columns to be in `select from`. I refer variable of `list` type as `_lst`.

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/q/31443864/5320906; the problem was a name collision.  It would be helpful if you could create an [mre]; the sample code is too generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blur error turns out to be that `select XXX as xxx from ...` has a int-type variable treated as alias of the column name when using ORM. I hope it helps since `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_set_parent_with_dispatch'` could occur under various circumstances.